# comparison with others at xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to result that who is the tallest. but i don't know how to i solve this.

```
<people> 
    <person id="1"> 
        <name>John</name> 
        <length>170</length> 
    </person> 
    <person id="2"> 
        <name>Michael</name> 
        <length>176</length> 
        </person> 
    <person id="3"> 
        <name>Noah</name> 
        <length>160</length> 
    </person> 
    <person id="4"> 
        <name>Jacob</name> 
        <length>186</length> 
    </person> 
    <person id="5"> 
        <name>James</name> 
        <length>178</length> 
    </person> 
</people>
```

How can i solve this problem by comparison operator?

Comment: Please say which XPath version you are using. Many XPath problems become much easier with later XPath versions, but many XPath users are stuck with version 1.0, so we really need to know.

Answer (score 0):

XPath 1.0 version. Use :

```
//person[length[not(.<//length)]]/name/text()
```

Output : `Jacob`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the person name you can use the below xpath.

```
//person[length[.=max(//person/length)]]/name/text()
```

[image]

Here is the simple xpath to get the length.

```
//person/length[text()=max(//person/length/text())]
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this requires XPath 2.0.